# Workflow of html5 drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html

I get confuse in using drag and drop. so far, it can drag and drop an element. But, I want to store the structure after I finish drop, so I add the dropped target into its parent which is after drop, and I find out that the ondragend called twice every time, and the ondrop called base on the numbers of target element. How to implement that?

```
function drop(){
  //this function is called base on the numbers of target element
  //drop third into first/second will be called once
  //drop second into first and then drop third into second will be called twice
}
function over(){
  //this function is called base on the numbers of total affected element
  //drop third into first/second will be called twice
  //drop second into first and then drop third into second will be called thrice
}
<div ondrop=drop ondragend=over id="first"></div>
<div ondrop=drop ondragend=over id="second"></div>
<div draggable=true id="third"></div>
```

Also I use return false in both drop and over also cannot fix the problem